# How do I use this subquery property in a MySQLi query?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Television website that I'm working on and I'm attempting to get the episodes from the episodes table that have been updated with assets the most recently. The two tables looks kind of like this:

```
episodes table
id        | show_id  |   title      | More information
5         |  47      | A cool title | Will our hero...

assets table 
id    | episode_id | show_id | last_updated
38    |      5     |    47   | 2019-08-24 18:35:37
39    |      5     |    47   | 2019-08-26 18:35:37
40    |      88    |    12   | 2019-08-22 18:35:37
```

Here are the conditions that I want:

1. I want to fetch the episode, or the episode left joined to the asset.
2. I want to only fetch the most recently updated episode per show (show_id)
3. I want to fetch 5 (or X number) of episodes.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM episodes
            WHERE id IN (
                SELECT episode_id
                FROM assets
                WHERE episode != '0'
                AND episode_id != '0'
                GROUP BY show_id
                ORDER BY last_updated DESC)
            LIMIT 5";
```

This almost works. It gets me 5 episodes, but all from the same show (the most recently updated show). I want the most recently updated episode from each show, but no duplicate shows.

Edit: Both tables have a show_id column.

Comment: What mysql version?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.17 x86

Comment: Please provide table create code as well as enough insert data rows and expected output.

Comment: Learning how to use `GROUP BY ` properly would be a good start.  What's the purpose of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.show_id,b.last_updated
FROM episodes A
INNER JOIN assets B ON A.ID=B.epsiode_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT Show_id,max(last_updated) as last_updated from assets group by show_id) C ON B.last_updated=C.last_updated and B.Show_id=C.Show_id
ORDER BY last_updated DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Hmmm. That kicks back false as the result. :(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the latest update of each show:

```
SELECT show_id, MAX(last_updated)
FROM assets 
GROUP BY show_id
ORDER BY MAX(t) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Now you find the episodes:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM assets a
JOIN (
    SELECT show_id, MAX(last_updated) as last_update
    FROM assets 
    GROUP BY show_id
    ORDER BY MAX(t) DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t
   ON a.show_id = t.show_id
  AND a.last_updated = t.last_updated
```

Now the episode info:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM episodes e
JOIN assets a
  ON e.id = a.episode_id
JOIN (
    SELECT show_id, MAX(last_updated) as last_update
    FROM assets 
    GROUP BY show_id
    ORDER BY MAX(t) DESC
    LIMIT 5
) t
   ON a.show_id = t.show_id
  AND a.last_updated = t.last_updated
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring in the assets information so you have the `show_id`.  Then you can look for the most recent:

```
SELECT e.*, a.*
FROM episodes e JOIN
     assets a
     ON e.id = a.episode_id
WHERE a.last_updated = (SELECT MAX(a2.last_updated)
                        FROM assets a2
                        WHERE a2.episode <> '0' AND
                              a2.episode_id <> '0'
                              a2.show_id = a.show_id
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Qoute from the question**
>
> Here are the conditions that I want:
>
> 1. I want to fetch the episode, or the episode left joined to the
>      asset.
> 2. I want to only fetch the most recently updated episode per show (show_id)
> 3. I want to fetch 5 (or X number) of episodes.

Without example data and or expected results it's a bit harder to suggest something.. 
 
But i think you are looking for

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
 /**
  * Get group maxes without using GROUP BY/MAX()
  *
  * "Simulates"
  *
  * SELECT 
  *   MAX(assets.last_updated)
  * FROM 
  *  assets
  * GROUP BY
  *  assets.episode_id   
  */
 SELECT
   assets1.*
 FROM
   assets assets1
 LEFT JOIN 
   assets assets2
 ON
    assets1.episode_id = assets2.episode_id
  AND
    assets1.last_updated <  assets2.last_updated
 WHERE
   assets2.id IS NULL
) AS assets
LEFT JOIN  
 episodes
ON
 assets.episode_id = episodes.id
ORDER BY
   assets.last_updated DESC
 , episodes.id DESC
LIMIT 
 5
```

**Result**

```
| id  | episode_id | show_id | last_updated        | id  | show_id | title        | More information |
| --- | ---------- | ------- | ------------------- | --- | ------- | ------------ | ---------------- |
| 39  | 5          | 47      | 2019-08-26 18:35:37 | 5   | 47      | A cool title | Will our hero... |
| 40  | 88         | 12      | 2019-08-22 18:35:37 |     |         |              |                  |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tg1nVAzj2EqHu2Amy7MvsX/1)

Pretty sure the more modern MySQL 5.7+ optimizers would flatten out by removing the redundant subquery and avoid the possible need into having to do delivered table materialization and execute below as more optimized version.

```
SELECT 
 *
 /**
  * Get group maxes without using GROUP BY/MAX()
  *
  * "Simulates"
  *
  * SELECT 
  *   MAX(assets.last_updated)
  * FROM 
  *  assets
  * GROUP BY
  *  assets.episode_id   
  */
FROM
   assets assets1
 LEFT JOIN 
   assets assets2
 ON
    assets1.episode_id = assets2.episode_id
  AND
    assets1.last_updated <  assets2.last_updated
LEFT JOIN  
 episodes
ON
 assets1.episode_id = episodes.id
WHERE
   assets2.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY
   assets1.last_updated DESC
 , episodes.id DESC
LIMIT 
 5
```